# Symfony and Doctrine 2 - filtering results based on related entity values

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

Given the following basic scenario:

```
Category
    - id
    - isDeleted

Product
    - id
    - Category
    - isDeleted
```

How can I filter Symfony/Doctrine query to only show Products whose own `isDeleted` value is false *and* their parent Category's `isDeleted` value is false?  I currently have:

```
$query = $em-createQuery("SELECT p FROM AppBundle:Product p WHERE p.quantity > 0 AND p.isDeleted = FALSE AND ORDER BY p.modifiedAt DESC");
```

But I'm unsure of how to move up the chain and also add something like `AND p.category.isDeleted = FALSE`.  Trying that, specifically, gives me a syntax error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there, just need to `JOIN` with the `category`:

```
SELECT p FROM AppBundle:Product p JOIN p.category c WHERE p.quantity > 0 
AND p.isDeleted = FALSE AND c.isDeleted = FALSE ORDER BY p.modifiedAt DESC
```